# Как увидить картинку что пришла с curl?

Tags: php, api, curl

задача отправить картинку CURL POST в ответ получить картинку обработаную API
вот POSTMAN

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а вот мой curl

```
    $post['file'] = new \CURLFile($dir, 'image/jpg', $name);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    dd(curl_exec($ch));
```

**приходит**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

помогите получить картинку и сохранить на сервере

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476212/save-image-from-url-with-curl-php

Comment: splash58  можна ваш телеграм? не совсем понятно как сохранить картинку...